# Should I store numbers in chars to save memory?

Tags: c++, variables

The question is pretty simple. Should I store some numbers which will not surpass 255 in a char or uint_8t variable types to save memory?

Is it common or even worth it saving a few bytes of memory?

Comment: It's common, but it's probably not worth doing it if you're having to ask this.

Comment: Unless your platform is extremely short on storage, or if you have to store a huge number of small numbers for some reason, then "no".

Comment: Unless you have to store large amounts of these numbers, I'd say no. Also keep in mind that `int` might be faster to work with (or at least not slower).

Comment: George, well everything must be started :)

Comment: Usually `int` is most efficient type. On some platforms using `int8_t` instead of `int` can have performance degradation.

Comment: I just mean that you probably don't need to do it. I'd say if you're really worried about running out of memory on an embedded device then it may be worth doing, but you can also use virtual memory. I wouldn't start using `char` over `int` in everyday programs, but there are other memory savings you can make that would maybe be worth implementing as common practice such as bit fields.

Comment: Are you memory constrained? If you are working on most common platforms with gigabytes of memory available, then you should just use the type that makes the code the simplest to read. *If* you are working on a memory constrained platform then *maybe* it makes sense to consider smaller types, but even then you need to check if your optimizing compiler doesn't already do the job for you when you just write the most simple code and let it do its job of optimizing it for you.

Comment: *even worth it saving a few bytes of memory?* only if you really, really need those few bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your processor and the amount of memory your platform has.
For 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit processors, it doesn't make a lot of sense.  On a 32-bit processor, it likes 32-bit quantities, so you are making it work a little harder.  These processors are more efficient with 32-bit numbers (including registers).

Remember that you are trading memory space for processing time.  Packing values and unpacking will cost more execution time than not packing.

Some embedded systems are space constrained, so restricting on size makes sense.

In present computing, reliability (a.k.a. robustness) and quality are high on the priority list.  Memory efficiency and program efficiency have gone lower on the priority ladder.  Development costs are also probably higher than worrying about memory savings.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, `int` is the "natural size" of integers on your platform. You many need a few extra bytes of code to read and write variables with other sizes. Still, if you got thousands of small values, a few extra bytes of code is worth the savings in data.

So, `std::vector<unsigned char> vc;` makes a lot more sense than just a single `unsigned char c;` value.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local variable, it mostly doesn't matter (from my experience different compilers with different optimization options do (usually negligibly) better with different type choices).

If it's saved elsewhere (static memory / heap) because you have **many** of those entities, then `uint_least8_t` is probably the best choice (the least and fast types are generally guaranteed to exists; the exact-width types generally are not).

`unsigned char` will reliably provide enough bits too (`UCHAR_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 255 and since `sizeof(unsigned char)` is guaranteed to be 1 and `sizeof(AnyType) >= 1`, there can be no unsigned integer type that's smaller).

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly on how many numbers you have to store.  If you have billions of them, then yes, it makes sense to store them as compactly as possible.  If you only have a few thousand, then no, it probably does not make sense.  If you have millions, it is debatable.